# Swift: Draw an overlay view with some elements on screen highlighted

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a UIViewController which has few elements that I have drawn programmatically.

Now I want to show few of those elements above a overlay in order to highlight them with a one-liner description.

```
class ExampleViewController: UIViewController {
    let element1 = UITextField()
    let element2 = UIButton()
    let overlayView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // ADDING ELEMENTS TO VIEW
        self.view.addSubview(self.element1)
        self.element1.text = "Some text"

        // ...other elements...

        //DRAWING MY OVERLAY WITH TRANSPARENCY
        self.overlayView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
        self.overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        self.overlayView.alpha = 0.4
        self.view.addSubview(self.overlayView)

    }

}
```

Problem I am facing are the following,

1. How do I bring the element on top of my semi-transparent overlay UIView?
2. How do I make the elements(that I bring forth) not have semi-transparency of overlay?

In other words, I want few elements to appear on top of my overlayView when I show the overlay.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is set the zPostion of the layers. This is done by

```
let view = UIView()
view.wantsLayer = true
view.layer?.zPosition = 1
```

for all your views and layers you can set them to different zPositions. The higher the number you set the higher up the layers it will go. Eg something at zPosition 10 will display below something that is zPosition 20. Hope this helps!

Comment: Tried zPosition, nothing changed. Not sure why.

Comment: I think its better if I just draw the elements again and add it as sub views of my overlayView. zPosition is not working.

Comment: did you make sure that all the things you were trying to reposition had wantsLayer = true  ? if you did then i dont know why thats not working because it should

Comment: UIView doesn't have wantsLayer property. I am using Swift 2.1